# Performant locking pattern

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking, task-parallel-library

I'm working on the below code and am trying to make it as fast as it can be.

Basically the execute method gets called every time an event gets triggered in the system. What I am testing for is to see whether x number of minutes have passed since a reduce was last performed. If x number of minutes have passed then we should execute the task.

Since the events can be triggered from any thread and happen quite quickly, I thought that triggering the task out side of the lock (even though its a task) would be better than having it in the lock.

Does anyone have any feedback on how this can be improved?

```
public class TriggerReduce
{ 
    private readonly object _lock = new object();
    private readonly int _autoReduceInterval = 5;
    private DateTime _lastTriggered;

    public void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        if (currentTime.Subtract(_lastTriggered).Duration().TotalMinutes > _autoReduceInterval)
        {
            var shouldRun = false;
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (currentTime.Subtract(_lastTriggered).Duration().TotalMinutes > _autoReduceInterval)
                {
                    _lastTriggered = currentTime;
                    shouldRun = true;
                }
            }

            if (shouldRun)
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    //Trigger reduce which is a long running task
                }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this actually a performance problem for you? Isn't this a premature optimization?

Comment: You could be right, but its a learning excise as much as anything. I'm wanting to make sure that I'm understanding how all the moving parts are working as much as anything.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I wouldn't do that!  Put the 'if (currentTime' and the 'shouldRun' stuff back inside the lock.

Don't change/check state outside a lock - it's sure to screw up.

In this case, a thread that has just set 'shouldRun' to true may have its decision reversed by another thread that enters and sets 'shouldRun' to false again before getting stuck on the lock.  The first thread then does not get to the 'StartNew' and the later thread won't either because the first thread set the _lastTriggered to the current time.

OTOH :)  since 'shouldRun' is an auto varaible and not a field, it is not state.  Only one thread can get inside the lock, double-check the interval and update the _lastTriggered time.

I don't like this kind of double-check but, at the moment, can't see why it would not work.

Comment: But `shouldRun` is not a field, one thread can't change the value of that variable on another thread.

Comment: Oh, you're right!  I deserve a downvote for an incorrect answer.

Comment: How come I end up with +1 for a wrong answer?  I'm not that bothered by the points, but it is confusing...  Maybe I will try some more wrong answers <g>

Comment: I have no idea. But you can always delete your answer, if you want.

Comment: @svick - yes, I could have done, but it might help some others if they understand why my answer was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use Monitor.TryEnter.

```
if (Monitor.TryEnter(_lock))
{
    try
    {
        if (currentTime.Subtract(_lastTriggered).Duration().TotalMinutes >
            _autoReduceInterval)
        {
            _lastTriggered = currentTime;
            shouldRun = true;
        } 
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(_lock);
    }
}
```

Comment: The C# team should have added a trylock keyword for Monitor.TryEnter, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be helpful to avoid the lock and use [Interlocked.Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.exchange.aspx) instead?

E.g.

```
private long _lastTriggeredTicks;

private DateTime lastTriggered
{
    get 
    { 
        var l = Interlocked.Read( ref _lastTriggeredTicks );
        return new DateTime( l );
    }
    set
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange( ref _lastTriggeredTicks, value );
    }
}
```

From what I understand [`Interlocked` is faster than a `lock`](http://kenegozi.com/blog/2010/01/01/interlocked-dot-increment-vs-dot--lock-ndash-surprise-surprise) statement.

Comment: And how would you use those in a way that doesn't cause a race condition?

Comment: Ah, I see, the `shouldRun` is a local variable only.

Comment: Still, you could have a race condition where two threads read `lastTriggered` at the same time, both decide they should run and then both set the property. How would you fix that race condition when using your property?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TriggerReduce //StartNew is fast and returns fast
{

    private readonly object _lock = new object();
    private readonly int _triggerIntervalMins = 5;

    private DateTime _nextTriggerAt = DateTime.MinValue;
    private bool inTrigger = false;

    public void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
            if (_nextTriggerAt > currentTime)
                return;

            _nextTriggerAt = currentTime.AddMinutes(_triggerIntervalMins);//runs X mins after last task started running (or longer if task took longer than X mins)
        }

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            //Trigger reduce which is a long running task
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }
}


public class TriggerReduce//startNew is a long running function that you want to wait before you recalculate next execution time
{

    private readonly object _lock = new object();
    private readonly int _triggerIntervalMins = 5;

    private DateTime _nextTriggerAt = DateTime.MinValue;
    private bool inTrigger = false;

    public void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentTime;
        lock (_lock)
        {
            currentTime = DateTime.Now;
            if (inTrigger || (_nextTriggerAt > currentTime))
                return;

            inTrigger = true;
        }
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            //Trigger reduce which is a long running task
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

        lock (_lock)
        {
            inTrigger = false;
            _nextTriggerAt = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(_triggerIntervalMins);//runs X mins after task finishes
            //_nextTriggerAt = currentTime.AddMinutes(_triggerIntervalMins);//runs X mins after last task started running (or longer if task took longer than X mins)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that this was a very good option as the lock is being invoked twice every time the execute method gets called.

Comment: for me only way to do it and be 100% sure it will have no thread execution conflicts. Codes proposed above can have on rare occasions execution of tasks in unpredictable times.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me. `StartNew()` finishes quickly, it doesn't wait for the task to finish.

Comment: you are correct...it spawns a new thread and runs it. i took it as a long running function.. in that case.. the second lock should run outside above execute function and be placed as last code on the tasks code.

Comment: added 2 ways of doing it depending of StartNew execution time

Answer (score 0):

I think you already have a fairly reasonable approach. The big problem is that you are accessing `_lastTriggered` outside of the lock. The double-checked locking idiom is not going to work here. Simply your code so that it looks like this.

```
public void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
    var shouldRun = false;
    lock (_lock)
    {
        TimeSpan span = currentTime - _lastTriggeed;
        if (span.TotalMinutes > _autoReduceInterval)
        {
            _lastTriggered = currentTime;
            shouldRun = true;
        }
    }

    if (shouldRun)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            //Trigger reduce which is a long running task
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }
}
```